# is Long domain names to be considered as spam by google or bad for SEO?

Tags: dns, spam, names

I will register 24 character a long domain name. Is long domain names considered spam by Google and is it bad for SEO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long domain names are not considered spam by Google and other search engines OR that it's bad for SEO. It could be bad for SEO if it is completely irrelevant to your site's content though - You wouldn't want a corporate site with a domain name of whycatslovecatnipandpurr.com, so stick to using your primary keyword(s) close to the beginning of the domain name. At the end of the day, search engines are merely interested in your site's content and the quality thereof. There have been rumours that Google dislikes long domains and domains with multiple hyphens, but this is all speculation and there is no documentation authored by Google that confirms it.

So, to sum it up: No, long domain names are not considered as spam or bad for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you wish to use the domain for spamming :)